# How to assign a subclassed NSManagedObject to a var (as opposed to a constant) in swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I've got an instance variable array of full of `Juice` objects that is subclassed from `NSManagedObject`, retrieved from an `NSFetch`.

I set the `UITableViewCell` title like this, with no problem:

```
let currentJuice = juiceList[indexPath.row]

cell.text = currentJuice.name
```

However, I'm trying to pass an instance of `Juice` between view controllers. I declare an instance variable `var selectedJuice = Juice()` variable and then in the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` I put:

```
 selectedJuice = juiceList[indexPath.row]
```

This line throws the error `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class` and I can't figure out why! I also don't know how to implement the designated init method in the `Juice` class, if anyone can help with that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Juice()` creates a Juice object without using the designated 
initialiser of `NSManagedObject`. And actually you don't need to assign a default
value to the property at all.

You should declare the property as an optional

```
var selectedJuice : Juice? // (1)
```

or implicitly unwrapped optional

```
var selectedJuice : Juice! // (2)
```

Then assigning

```
selectedJuice = juiceList[indexPath.row]
```

should work without problem.

In the first case (1), you would access the property as

```
if let theJuice = selectedJuice {
    // ...
} else {
    // no Juice selected
}
```

In the second case (2), you would access the property simple as `selectedJuice`,
and you get a runtime exception if it is not set (`nil`).

Comment: Ah, I see. I was pretty sure the `Juice()` was the problem but couldn't figure it out. Thanks Martin!